# scheme adds 5 to all of the Grades in a given list and updates the letter

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to design a function that adds 5 to all of the grades in a given list and updates its letter grade.

Here's the data definition for grade,

```
;; A Grade is: (make-grade Symbol Number)
(define-struct grade (letter num))
```

The Symbol in a Grade represents:

```
'A  >= 90,'B  >= 80,'C  >= 70,'D  >= 60,'F  < 60
```

test list,

```
(define grades 
(list (make-grade 'D 62) (make-grade 'C 79) (make-grade 'A 93) (make-grade 'B 84) 
      (make-grade 'F 57) (make-grade 'F 38) (make-grade 'A 90) (make-grade 'A 95)
      (make-grade 'C 76) (make-grade 'A 90) (make-grade 'F 55) (make-grade 'C 74)
      (make-grade 'A 92) (make-grade 'B 86) (make-grade 'F 43) (make-grade 'C 73)))
```

I'm wondering how to updates the grade letter base on its current state to the List of Grades, do we use build-list and then cond the conditions? or something else?

For just adding 5 to all of the grades, i can simply use **map** function,

```
;; add5: Lof[Grade] -> Lof[grade-num] 
;; adds 5 to all of the Grades in a given list 

(define (add5 log)
  (map 
   (lambda (a-grade) 
     (+ (grade-num a-grade) 5)) 
     log))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This clearly shows that your design is flawed. `grade` should just be a number, and the letter can at any time be computed from the number. But as it stands you have redundant information in your structure and redundancy is what is creating you a problem here.

Comment: BTW, if there is a maximum value for grade (for example 99) you'd want to check in your `add5` procedure that the result is not higher than your maximum.

Comment: @LePetitPrince Grade is a structure that contains grade letter and grade number. So here's one way i'm thinking to do it in a easier form. First, i divide the grade list to two parts, pure numbers and pure letters. I can build a list of numbers add5 and check non of them are over 100. and then cope the number with grade letter list one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` for this, simply create a new grade with the updated values. Just be careful if the current grade number plus `5` is greater than `100`, in my code I added the restriction that no grade can be greater than `100`. Assuming that you have implemented a procedure that converts grade numbers into letters (let's call it `number->letter`), this is one possible solution:

```
(define (add5 log)
  (map (lambda (grade)
         (let ((new-grade (+ (grade-num grade) 5)))
           (if (<= new-grade 100)
               (make-grade (number->letter new-grade) new-grade)
               (make-grade 'A 100))))
       log))
```

Comment: thanks Oscar! i have the function deal with the grade conversion.

Comment: Dear drive-by downvoter: care to comment? if this answer can be improved in any way I'd like to know it. A downvote with no comments and no apparent reason isn't helpful at all.